# Auto backup of MS SQL Server on FTP

Tags: c#, ftp, sql-server-2008-r2

I have managed to take auto-backup mentioned in the following link on ms sql server express edition.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019698

i would like to know if there is a way i can take this backup automatically on some ftp location.

The above link suggest it to take backup on local drive.

Comment: write a script that transfers your local backup to the FTP server. SQL server itself probably can't backup to ftp on its own.

Comment: cant we create a batch file script for uploading to FTP location?

Comment: that is exactly what I suggested...